# Animate ng-hide with UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-animate

I have a form where I am using ng-hide at the bottom of the page to hide a div containing a UI-Grid table, as suggested by the *[Hidden Grids](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/108_hidden_grids)* tutorial in the docs. When the user hits the submit button, the grid is made visible as expected but its reveal is not animated.  The strange part is that the div containing the grid appears to animate perfectly fine.

I have replicated the problem in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RidGGwJwS26bpDnqtLg1) and here is the relevant code for reference.  This one is really stumping me, so any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

HTML

```
<h4><a href="#" ng-click="hidden = ! hidden">Reveal</a></h4>
<div class="background animate-hide" ng-hide="hidden">
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}

.background {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.animate-hide {
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out 0.1s !important;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-out !important;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 260px;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

}

Comment: yeah, for virtualized data, animate won't work. maybe this answer will help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901013/how-to-animate-angular-ui-grid-when-rows-are-added

Comment: @sfletche it can be animated and it has nothing to do with virtualized data.  It turned out to be a simple css issue

Comment: right on. glad to hear it. thanks for keeping me in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the grid has an explicit height set, it is overflowing the `.background` div.  The default value of the `overflow` CSS property is `visible`, so that means the grid will overflow the dimensions of its container and be completely visible.

You can fix this by adding `overflow: hidden` to your `.animate-hide` class:

```css
.animate-hide {
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out 0.1s !important;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-out !important;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's an updated plunker showing the effect: http://plnkr.co/edit/3kO5HqSZTGVM8A3YScYq?p=preview

Comment: I can't believe how many hours trying to figure out if the problem had to do with the way ui-grid virtualized data, or if the changes in Angular 1.4 were somehow impacting things.  It didn't even occur to me that it was a stupid little css thing.  I guess this is a good lesson in not assuming that a problem is more complicated than it really is.  Thanks so much for your help!